# Find where is a shared library symbol defined on a live system / list all symbols exported on a system

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking

Basically, this is two questions into one - because if I can list all symbols exported within a system, along with their shared library path, then I could simply `grep` that output.

For kernel symbols, I guess it is somewhat easier - because we can always `cat /proc/kallsyms` and get a list of all symbols of those modules loaded in memory; then `sudo cat /proc/modules` will give a list of loaded modules with their addresses, but not the paths where does modules have been loaded from (if they are built as separate, out-of-tree .ko objects)

For instance, I try to trace the program `kst` using `ltrace`:

```
$ ltrace kst2
...
_ZNK13QGraphicsItem10parentItemEv(0xa1ccdb4, 0, 0xbfe631a8, 0x823652b, 0xbfe63298) = 0xa1ce854
__dynamic_cast(0xa1ce854, 0x839ff00, 0x8306b80, 84, 0xbfe63298)     = 0xa1ce800
_ZNK13QGraphicsItem10parentItemEv(0xa1ccdb4, 0x839ff00, 0x8306b80, 84, 0xbfe63298) = 0xa1ce854
__dynamic_cast(0xa1ce854, 0x839ff00, 0x8306b80, 84, 0xbfe63298)     = 0xa1ce800
...
```

... and I would like to know where this `_ZNK13QGraphicsItem10parentItemEv` resides.

So, what to do about shared library symbols? Reading through [[gcc-help] Re: finding the library in which symbol is defined.](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2004-01/msg00274.html); I tried something like this:

```
$ find /usr/lib -name '*.so*' -exec nm --print-file-name --defined-only --dynamic {} \; | grep "QGraphicsItem"
...
/usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4.7.2:00766d70 T _Zls6QDebugN13QGraphicsItem16GraphicsItemFlagE
/usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4.7.2:00766aa0 T _Zls6QDebugN13QGraphicsItem18GraphicsItemChangeE
/usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4.7.2:00767e80 T _Zls6QDebugP13QGraphicsItem
...
```

... but that gives me additional problems: I don't really know all the paths which are scanned for shared libraries on my system, so when I first tried `find /lib ...` it didn't find anything; I find this guessing of directories irksome, just as well as the alternative: scanning the entire root filesystem with `find` ... And also, I seem to hit up *.so's which cannot be opened by `nm` (maybe because they are symlinks?), which output a quite a bit of error messages (which I don't like either).

The thing is - `ldd` (or `ld`?) probably performs some of this lookup of symbols, but I tried the respective manpages, and I cannot see a way to "find" any symbol from the command line, without providing some sort of executable file as an argument. Side question - would there a way to use these tools for that?

So, what I'm looking for a command line tool, which would behave something like (pseudocode):

```
$ ./findsymbol '_Zls6QDebugN13QGraphicsItem16GraphicsItemFlagE'
symbol found in:
    /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4.7.2:00766d70 T _Zls6QDebugN13QGraphicsItem16GraphicsItemFlagE
...
```

... where I don't specify any directories to search - but which would also handle, e.g. `LD_PRELOAD` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`; say if I do:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD="/path/to/mylib.so" ./findsymbol '*mylib_print*'
```

... then I'd get the `/path/to/mylib.so` where the given symbol was defined (given that such a symbol wouldn't exist in the standard libraries) - and would output "not found" otherwise. And otherwise, `./findsymbol --dumpall` could produce a list of all available symbols and their locations seen from a given environment (e.g. a specific `bash` shell).

Does a tool like this exist for Linux?

Answer (score 21):

The paths to look for libraries in will be listed in the file `/etc/ld.so.conf`, the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and any RPATHs encoded into the ELF binary.  The program `ldd` will tell you what libraries a specific application will load.

Once you have a symbol you are curious about, you can use the program `nm` to dump symbols of `.o` and `.a` files and `readelf` to dump symbols from a `.so` or any elf executable.

Examples:

```
nm -g /usr/lib/blah.a
readelf -Ws /usr/lib/blah.so
```

And finally, with that background aside, here is your holy grail:

Given a symbol `_ZN6Kopete6Global10PropertiesC2Ev`, where is this?

```
scanelf -l -s _ZN6Kopete6Global10PropertiesC2Ev | grep _ZN6Kopete6Global10PropertiesC2Ev
```

which yields:

```
ET_DYN _ZN6Kopete6Global10PropertiesC2Ev /usr/lib64/libkopete.so.4.11.4
```

The `-l` flag says to search dirs in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and the `-s` specifies the symbol to find.

Comment: This is incomplete: some programs load libraries from application-specific directories.

Comment: @Gilles `scanelf` allows you to specify specific directories to search in and support recursive seaching with `-r` so you can tweak its search paths or search your entire system without too much trouble.  For example `scanelf -r -s SYMBOL /lib/* /usr/* /opt/*` will find most of the places libraries are hiding.

Comment: @casey I think you mean `-R` for recursive search, see [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scanelf) page. Also, the `*` at the end of `/lib/*` is probably redundant.

Answer (score 9):

On GNU systems (when using the GNU libc dynamic linker), you can run your program as:

```
LD_DEBUG=bindings kst2
```

To find where the symbols resolve to.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this a number of times, trying to port code from one Linux system to another. Usually I just end up grep'ing all the standard directories. I couldn't find anything googling. So here is a quick script:

[edt11x/findinsharedlibs](https://gist.github.com/edt11x/13212082576ca7ceba227422e621c8d8)