# Finding out functions/variables used in the code from a given shared library

Tags: linux, c++, shared-library

I'm analysing a large C++ project on linux platform(redhat), specifically the shared libraries used in it. How can I find which symbols(functions/variables) are used in this project from a particular shared library?

To begin I ran the following command on my binary:

```
readelf -d binaryName | grep -i "Shared library"
```

and I got a list of shared libraries which are used in my project(ldd shows a longer list as these shared libraries have their own dependencies as well) e.g.

```
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libuv.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libssl.so.1.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcrypto.so.1.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libz.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Now is there a way to find out which symbols from, say, `libuv.so.1` are used in the project's codebase. Can anyone suggest some roadmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nm -uD /path/to/your/binary
```

will list all the undefined dynamic symbols in your binary. You then need to match that with the output of

```
nm -gD /path/to/a/library
```

for each library listed by your `readelf` command to determine which library provides each symbol.

Note that this doesn’t necessarily give a complete picture; in particular, libraries and symbols accessed through `libdl` won’t be taken into account. If you’re willing to *run* the binary, and it uses the GNU C library’s dynamic loader (`ld.so`, or rather `ld-linux.so` on Linux), you can list all the symbol bindings in detail by running the binary with `LD_DEBUG=bindings` set in its environment. See `man ld.so` for details.

Comment: 'nm -gD /path/to/library' outputs different types of symbols e.g. T, W, U, i, A etc. Would you agree that I need to skip the U category? If yes, are there some other categories which I need to skip? Is there a flag which will just give me the required(for my case) category of symbols?

Comment: If you’re only interested in functions, you can ignore everything apart from T. I’m not aware of a flag to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Using the information provided in the accepted answer [and here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103751/278729), I've created the following script for finding all the symbols which are currently being used in the binary(taken from the shared library). The script takes 1 argument i.e. the name of the binary(path required if binary is in a different directory than the script).

The script will display the shared libraries needed by the binary file given in input. All the symbols will be dumped into an output file(result.txt)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "1 argument needed in the script"
    echo "e.g. $0 [binary name(complete path)]"
    exit
fi

if [ -f $1 ]
then
    echo "Going to find the unresolved symbols found in \"$1\""
else
    echo "Binary file \"$1\" not found. Check name/path."
fi

binaryFile=$1

lddOutput=(`ldd $binaryFile | awk '{print $3}' | grep -v "0x" | awk 'NF >0'`)

#echo "$lddOutput"

sharedDependencies=()

echo "Given below are the shared libraries used in $1"
for lib in "${lddOutput[@]}"
do
    sharedDependencies+=($lib)
    ls -lrta $lib
done

rm -f allSymbols.temp
rm -f result.txt

# Iterate the loop to read and print each array element
#echo -e "\nGiven below are the dependencies found for $binaryFile\n"
#echo "SharedDependencies: ${sharedDependencies}"
for lib in "${sharedDependencies[@]}"
do
#echo "Will search below lib in sharedDependencies"
#echo $lib
#Create list of all text symbols from all the libraries
#for symbol in `nm -gD $lib | awk '{$1=""}1' | grep " T \| W \| V \| w \| v \| t " | awk '{print $2}'`;
#for symbol in `nm -gD $lib | grep -i " T \| W \| V "`;
nm -gD $lib | grep -i " T \| W \| V \| I " | while read symbol;
do
string=
sym=
#echo -e "\nsymbol->$symbol" >> debug.txt
n=`echo $symbol | awk "{print NF}"`
#echo -e "n->$n\n" >> debug.txt
if [ $n -eq 2 ]
then
sym=`echo $symbol | awk '{print $2}'`
else
sym=`echo $symbol | awk '{print $3}'`
fi

string="$lib contains $sym"
echo $string >> allSymbols.temp
#echo $string >> debug.txt
done
done

undefinedDynamicSymbols=`nm -uD $binaryFile | awk '{print $2}'`
#echo -e "\n\nUndefinedDynamicSymbols\n$undefinedDynamicSymbols\n"

for undefinedSymbol in $undefinedDynamicSymbols;
do
echo $undefinedSymbol >> result.txt
grep  -w $undefinedSymbol allSymbols.temp >> result.txt
echo -e "\n" >> result.txt
done

echo "symbols dumped in result.txt"

rm -f allSymbols.temp
```